# Instantiate prefab disabled scripts

Tags: unity, models

I'm creating a script to dynamicly load a menu with buttons.
On every button there is a script that need to be run when the button has been clicked. For the button there is a prefab where the script in enabled on. After instantiating the prefab the script on it has been disabled. When I manually enable it by code it does nothing. When enabling the script using the editor it does wor.

My code for generating the buttons on my menu looks like:

```
 foreach (BuildingModel model in models)
    {
          GameObject tempButton = Instantiate(buttonPrefab);

          PlaceObjectToScene script = tempButton.GetComponent<PlaceObjectToScene>();

           script.objectName = model.modelLocation + "/" + model.modelName + ".fbx";

           script.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            script.enabled = true;

            tempButton.transform.SetParent(horizontalLayoutGroup.transform);

    }
```

I searched on the internet for some answers and found forum thread with the same issue but non of the sollutions works in my situation. Can someone help me how to enable the script that is default enabled on the prefab?

Comment: 1. Check if PREFABS have script enabled (not the objects on the scene).
2. Check if you have any errors in the console. If there's an error in the script, it will become `disabled`.

Comment: Script is enabled in the prefab and did not got any errors in the script

Comment: `Assets -> Export Package` and upload it on `Dropbox` or somewhere. There's no error in this code, I'll take a look.

Comment: You can find the assets here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7tTtE3e6xrTVERhMWMybE1ndWs/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: It's about PreFab with name MenuButton. Script LoadSubMenu will initialize Prefab and PlaceObjectToScene script is in the prefab.

Comment: 400 mb :D give me a minute

Comment: I can't load it. It's size is like 123GB's when unpacked. Are all components disabled, or just the `PlaceObjectToScene` one?

Comment: I will create another package this evening with even more stuff disable

Comment: Here you can find the lighter version of my package. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7tTtE3e6xrTTkV3M3g0emEzekU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the issue. It was an error in my code. I had added a enabled = false in there. And is not the correct behaviour of my script.